# Closing a pull request through github API

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-api

As per the design requirements of our application, we used to delete the merge requests in Gitlab using gitlab API. Now we are migrating to Github and I am looking for a similar API call which closes the pull requests on Github.

I read through the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/), but it doesn't answer my question.

I would be glad if someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request) whose link you pasted above, it seems that there is an update endpoint which can be used to assign the state of a pull request:

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number

{
    "title": "new title",
    "body": "updated body",
    "state": "closed",
    "base": "master"
}
```

The `state` key inside the JSON can be either `open` or `closed`.

Comment: @TIm how can I close MR by direct appeal to api? But what about security? you probably forgot about the token