# How to close a pull request in GitHub using Jenkins Jobs

Tags: github, jenkins, pull-request

I have a problem, how to close a pull request using Jenkins jobs.

my goal is, I can get a branch, using this branch name to find, if under this branch, a pull request existed.

if yes, then I close this pull request through Github API.

1. Question, How to get pull request ID through Branch name?

2: if I get pull request ID, how to close this pull request.

Any Solutions?

I finde

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing a pull request through github API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343739/closing-a-pull-request-through-github-api)

Comment: I also found this solution, but I can I get pull request ID using branch name?